# generating a list with eliminated some elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Our desired list is

```
desiredx=[[u, 5, 6], [u, 6, 7],[u, 7, 8],[u, 8, 9],[u, 11, 12],[u, 12, 13],[u, 13, 14],
          [u, 16, 17],[u, 17, 18],[u, 18, 19],[u, 20, 21],[u, 21, 22],[u, 22, 23],[u, 23, 24]]
```

in which some elements have eliminated

```
eliminated=[[u, 9, 10],[u, 14, 15],[u, 19, 20]]
```

I could generate `desiredx` separately by four other lists with `L=30`

```
V1= [[u,i,(i+1)] for i in range(5,L-9,5)]

V2= [[u,i+1,(i+2)] for i in range(5,L-9,5)] 

V3= [[u,i+2,(i+3)] for i in range(5,L-9,5)] 

V4= [[u,i+3,(i+4)] for i in range(5,L-9,5)]
```

and combination all of them. **My question**: Is there any easier way to generate `desiredx` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a condition on `i`, to avoid `9, 14, 19`, you check the `(i+1)%5` result

```
res = [[u, i, i + 1] for i in range(5, L - 5) if (i + 1) % 5 != 0]
```

Comment: Wonderful!!! and Intelligent!!!